# How do I output an error when I'm determining how to output an error?

Tags: api-design, error-handling, errors, error-messages

I've written an API which can be configured to signal errors in different ways (return values, debugging messages, or exceptions). I've got a check in place when the API is first initialized to see what type of error handling the client is requesting - what should I do when they request an undefined error handling type?

This is kind of similar to "Where do I log the error that I can't write to the logfile?"

Do I go with the idiom of the language, do I fatal? Do I throw an exception, even though if they aren't asking for exception handling they probably haven't wrapped the call in a try/catch? The language I'm writing doesn't have an ENUM type so it can't be a type error.

Comment: Assume a default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see only a couple of choices:

- Assume the most common default and use it
- Crash (fatal error / configuration error)
- Walk through your different options until you find one that works (i.e., if the most common default is 'write to file' and you don't have a file name, keep falling back to different options until you get to one you know works)
- Use all available options at the same time (i.e., throw a config error AND return and error code AND write to the console AND ...)

Personally, I'd probably crash with a fatal configuration error, but your situation may be different.

Comment: I was wavering on that, but I think fataling is the way to go here, based on the context